# How to find Active Directory container from registry

Tags: active-directory, registry, registrykey

I am looking for a way to retrieve a computers Active Directory container from the registry stored on that same machine.  Is there any registry key in Windows that would contain the full LDAP path for the computer object?

Ex. Computers\MyDomain.local

Comment: doubt it. a machine shouldn't care WHERE it is in the AD tree - it's up to the AD server to send over any applicable policies. You can get the full path if you turn on the "Advanced Features" view option in the ADUaC tool, which adds an "Object" tab to every object's properties windows, which will contain the full AD path.

Answer (score 3):

It should be located in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine, string value called "Distinguished-Name"

I think this will be the location as of the last successful group policy refresh.

Comment: It'd be best to get the DN from AD directory. But I got stuck with SCCM running a compliance script that couldn't access the network. This reg path worked perfect. Thank you!

Comment: This is definitely the best answer.

If anyone wants a PowerShell one-liner for this:                                         
`Get-Item 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine' | Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name 'Distinguished-Name'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that information is stored in the registry.  You should be able to issue an LDAP request to get the computer's distinguished name.  If your directory admins are following convention, the machine name should be the common name in the directory so your filter should be something like `(cn=MachineName)`.